# Conditionals won't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, conditional-statements

Okay so me and my friend are programming a small basic torture game and when I try to run my part of the code, some of the if/elif it will not run as if they were False when they seem True

```
lives = 5
lives_1 = 13
random_number = random.randint(0,100)
random_number_1 = random.randit(0,1000)
        while lives > 0:
            print random_number # delete in final product
            print "'You have %d chances to save your partner'" % (lives)
            guess_0 = int(raw_input("Guess a number from 1 to 100 "))
            print "You have guessed %d" % (guess_0)
            proceed_2 = raw_input("Press 'Enter' to proceed")
            if guess_0 != random_number: # This works
                print "It is incorrect, your partner loses a finger"
                lives -= 1
                continue
            elif guess_0 == random_number: # This works
                print "It is correct you and your partner get to walk free"
                print "GAME OVER"
                break
            elif guess > random_number: # Doesn't work
                print "'LOWER!'"
            elif guess < random_number: # Doesn't work
                print "'HIGHER!'"
        else:
            print "GAME OVER"

    while lives_1 > 0:
        print random_number_1 # delete in final product
        print "'You ha-- %d ch---e-'" % (lives_1)
        guess_1 = raw_input("What should you do? ")
        proceed_1 = raw_input("Press Enter to proceed")
        print "You decided to shout {}".format(guess_1)
        if guess_1 == random_number_1:
            print "The cult has decided to let you go" # doesn't work
            break
        elif guess_1 != random_number_1: # Works but also works when false
            lives_1 -= 1
            if lives_1 < 5:
                print "Tears begin to blind you as you're nearing death"
            continue
        elif guess_1 < random_number_1: # doesn't work 
            print "You squeel in agony as one of your nails were ripped off"
            print "'Higher'"
        elif guess_1 > random_number_1: #doesn't work
            print "You squeel in agony as one of your nails were ripped off"
            print "'LOWER...'" 
    else:
        print "GAME OVER"
```

I want it to print out larger or larger than 3 but as you can see it won't. I have the same problem with the other one.

For the second while function, when I enter a number lower or larger than random_number(_1) it won't print out larger or lower and if I enter the value for random_number(_1) it won't run. I can't see anything wrong please help

Comment: [**Minimal**, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: At a glance it's probably because `input` returns a `str` and you're comparing an `int` with this `str` at some point.

Comment: @Unatiel can you specify where, please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here ist that your condition

```
guess > random_number
```

is an else if of

```
guess_0 != random_number
```

and

```
guess_0 == random_number
```

meaning it will only get evaluated if NONE of the former two have evaluated to True. As you can see this cannot be the case. You can instead write it like this:

```
        if guess_0 == random_number:
            print "It is correct you and your partner get to walk free"
            print "GAME OVER"
            break
        if guess_0 != random_number:
            print "It is incorrect, your partner loses a finger"
            lives -= 1
            if guess > random_number:
                print "'LOWER!'"
            elif guess < random_number:
                print "'HIGHER!'"
```

In your second while loop you should edit the line

```
guess_1=raw_input(....)
```

to

```
guess_1=int(raw_input(....))
```

Comment: thank you for pointing it out I have made the changes for the first while loop, but I also have a problem with the second while loop. And what I mean for don't work is, for example when random_number = 43 and when I enter 43 it still produces a "Try again" result.

Comment: another example is when I enter 2 and random_number = 43 but it'll print out "lower"

Comment: Your forgot to convert the raw_input to int. it shoudl bei guess_1=int(raw_input(...)).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try simplifying your conditionals to this?

```
if guess_0 == random_number:
   print "It is correct you and your partner get to walk free"
   print "GAME OVER"
   break
else:
   print "It is incorrect, your partner loses a finger"
   lives -= 1
   if guess_0 > random_number:
       print "'LOWER!'"
   else:
       print "'HIGHER!'"
```

This principle should also apply to your second loop that you had asked about.

Comment: Thank you and I've made the changes but for some reason my 2nd while loop prints out weird stuff like when I enter 2 and random_number = 43 but it'll print out "lower" or when I enter 43 but it comes out incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You may avoid to use the `while` loop until you are obliged, it may be better with a `for` loop.

In case of a bug appear on exit loop condition, `while` loop could end with infinite loop, which may result to a computer freeze or heavy ressource load ...

Comment: Thank you but for some reason, it's easier for me to comprehend while loops than for loops, but I'll learn more about now